# Check if req.param.dogid / req.param.dogname in Express Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, postman

I have 2 GET functions in the same file.

one for dogid and the other for dogname.

```
//Operations for api/dogs/{dogId} route
//get operation
 router.get('/:dogId', async (req,res)=>{   
      try{
          const dog = await Dogs.findById(req.params.dogId);
          res.json(dog);
      }catch(error){
          res.json({message:error});
      }
  
  })
```

And

```
//Operations for api/dogs/{dogName} route
 //get operation
 router.get('/:dogName', async (req,res)=>{   
      try{
          const dog = await Dogs.find({'name': { $in: req.params.dogName}})
          res.json(dog);
      }catch(error){
          res.json({message:error});
      }
  
  })
```

When I try npm start it doesn't give any problem.

But in Postman when I send GET operation for http://localhost:3000/api/dogs/Sasha

then it shows the following:

```
{
    "message": {
        "stringValue": "\"Sasha\"",
        "valueType": "string",
        "kind": "ObjectId",
        "value": "Sasha",
        "path": "_id",
        "reason": {},
        "name": "CastError",
        "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"Sasha\" (type string) at path \"_id\" for model \"Doggies\""
    }
}
```

The code for getting the data with dogname is already present. But since the get function for the dogid route is written before the dogname route it's showing this error.

Comment: I guess we need to add a condition in api/dogs/{dogId} route which will check if the /:dogId parameter is actually an ObjectId or not. But I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that GET api/dogs/:dogId is handling the request since it is written before GET api/dogs/:dogname.

To solve this problem try changing your api design or using different HTTP request methods. For example :

```
POST api/dogs/:dogId
GET api/dogs/:dogName

or GET api/animals/dogs/:dogId
   GET api/dogs/:dogName
```

But don't do this:

```
   GET api/dogs/:dogId
   GET api/dogs/:dogName
```

Comment: I suppose camelcasing a word doesn't solve the issue. Still, it will check and tell soon

Comment: It doesn't work. I bet something should be done by testing the req.params.dogId. I just can't figure out what

Comment: If stills gives the same error about Casting to Object Id failed then what you are doing is making a get request to localhost:3000/api/dogs/(invalid mongodb id)

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to GET the dog with the name. Also I got another get operation for the ObjectId

Answer (score 1):

As @Mohammad Ismail already pointed out, you need to use different HTTP Method to differentiate between 2 routes.

There's another approach is to use `query` instead of `param`
You send the request like `localhost:3000/api/dog?dogName=abc`
Then in your code: `req.query.dogName` will get you the value `abc`

Comment: Yes, we discussed this issue. Since we can't have the same route for two, 1st one with dogId will remain as it is. And we will use dogeName as a query. I was not introduced to query. For this I was stuck. After a few searching now I've understood. Thanks.

Comment: Great to hear that it you can make it work, happy coding!